# How to force `telnet` (in TCP mode) to send bytes immediately?

Tags: linux, tcp, telnet, buffer

In Linux, when I run `telnet <address> <port>` and then type things, it buffers data and only sends collected line when I hit Enter. Furthermore, it buffers up to 4096 characters and truncates everything else.

I can confirm this by listening to the traffic via tcpdump or anything like this.

Is it possible to send bytes (or multibytes if UTF-8 encoding of character is multibyte) immediately when it appears? I expect to see "1-byte" (1 payload byte plus headers) TCP packets in the tcpdump output.

Or, at least, is it possible to force it to send the collected buffer without `<cr>` or/and `<lf>` characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `telnet` client, specifically, is designed to speak to a Telnet server using the Telnet protocol; it will switch to character mode if it receives Telnet IAC WILL SGA / IAC DO SGA from the server.

Alternatively, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> and enter `mode character` to initiate this from the client side; the client will send the Telnet IAC negotiation messages *to* the server and will switch to character-by-character mode. If the server is not a Telnet server, this will result in it receiving a few garbage characters before your input.

On the other hand, for programs like `nc` or `ncat` (i.e. *not* Telnet clients), which keep the local tty in "cooked" mode, this buffering is done by the tty and not by the program. Either a) press Ctrl+D at any point to make the tty return the text that was typed so far, or b) use `stty raw` to switch the tty to raw mode before starting the program (and `stty cooked iutf8 -brkint` to switch back).

(Ctrl+D isn't just the EOF key, it's the "end of read() call" key. Pressing Ctrl+D on an *empty* line, i.e. making the read() return nothing, is what actually gives EOF; whereas Ctrl+D after some input will return just that input, without any trailing CR/LF.)

Comment: Yes. Sure. I missed that `mode character`. Also nice suggestion about netcat. Thank you!